# How does it save the result from the list to a .txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math

In this code, the script takes all coordinates *(x, y)* from the **"Base.txt"** file, but unfortunately saves the result to the **"Save.txt"** file only from line # 1, and skips the rest of the coordinate line value in the list.

```
from ecpy.curves
import Curve,Point

with open("Base.txt", "rt") as base:
    for line in base.read().splitlines():
        x, y = map(lambda v: int(v, 16), line[1: -1].split(" , "))

cv = Curve.get_curve('secp256k1')

A  = Point(x,y,cv)

C  = 6

B  = A*C

with open("Save.txt", "w") as file:
    print(B,file=file, sep="\n")
```

How does it save all the results from the list to the **"Save.txt"** file?

Comment: I don't give an answer as I confirm the other answer in the comments. However, I just recommend you to state your problems more Clearly. You could have explained more about how curve and point are actually implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop

```
with open("Base.txt", "rt") as base:
    for line in base.read().splitlines():
        x, y = map(lambda v: int(v, 16), line[1: -1].split(" , "))
```

Overwrites `x` and `y` for each line.
You should include everything in the for loop, and open the file in 'append' mode, and also use the `write` function on the file.

```
from ecpy.curves
import Curve,Point

with open("Base.txt", "rt") as base:
    for line in base.read().splitlines():
        x, y = map(lambda v: int(v, 16), line[1: -1].split(" , "))

        cv = Curve.get_curve('secp256k1')
    
        A  = Point(x,y,cv)

        C  = 6

        B  = A*C

        with open("Save.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(str(B))  # should implement the __str__ or __repr__ method
            file.write("\n")
```

Comment: Writes an error: Traceback (most recent call last):  `in <module>
    file.write(B)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Point`

Comment: Might be necessary to convert the point to a string. You can do `str(B)`, after implementing the `__str__` method of that class.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/22460/python-str-repr-functions) could help. Basically you have to create a method that defines how you wish to represent the data. I would say you can print something like `f"Point(x=self.x, y=self.y)"`.